# Convert Objective C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

So i started learning swift directly and i'm trying to convert this objective C to swift but not sure exactly what it means, can someone explain it?

```
Side1 = ([[[ValueArray objectAtIndex:Counter-1] objectAtIndex:2] intValue] == 1)?-1:1;
```

where, Side = 0,ValueArray = [] and Counter = 0

Edit: Its in loop so counter++
Thanks

Comment: If `Counter` is equal to 0, `[ValueArray objectAtIndex:Counter-1]` should crash.

Comment: `NSArray *intermediateArray = [ValueArray objectAtIndex:Counter-1];.
if ([intermediateArray objectAtIndex:2] intValue] == 1){Side1= -1;}else{Side1=1;}`. Easier to understand?

Answer (score 2):

```
if ([[[ValueArray objectAtIndex:Counter-1] objectAtIndex:2] intValue] == 1) {
    Side1 = -1
} else {
    Side1 = 1
}
```

What is inside of `ValueArray`? Also, if `Counter == 0` then getting `objectAtIndex` -1 will crash. But basically the swift version would be:

`(ValueArray[Counter-1][2] as! NSString).intValue == 1`

This makes a couple of assumptions, mainly that you're returning a `String` which we can force downcast to an `NSString` to take advantage of `intValue`.

Comment: https://github.com/GuntisTreulands/JigsawDemo/blob/master/JigsawExample/MainViewController.m thats the code I'm converting

Comment: You should start trying to convert it and then ask questions as they come up (if you have them). Unfortunately SO is not really the place for "here is some kind, please convert it for me".

Comment: ofcourse i'm converting it myself, i just got stuck there thats why i asked.

Answer (score 2):

This is shorthand for `if`-`else`. It can be used like so:

```
my_variable = (some_condition ? some_value : some_other_value)
```

This is equivalent to

```
if some_condition
    my_variable = some_value
else
    my_variable = some_other_value
```

It seems your code checks the integer value of an object in an array inside another array. It can be converted to Swift like so:

```
Side1 = (ValueArray[Counter - 1][2] as! Int == 1 ? -1 : 1)
```

As mentioned in a comment, this will crash if `Counter` is 0. I'm also assuming that `ValueArray` only contains objects that can be casted to `Int`. Swift is usually very picky about these things.

**EDIT**

If `ValueArray` contains *strings*, they can't be casted to `Int`. Cast to `NSString` first:

```
ValueArray[Counter - 1][2] as! NSString
```

and therefore the `if` shorthand becomes

```
Side1 = ((ValueArray[Counter - 1][2] as! NSString).intValue == 1 ? -1 : 1)
```

Comment: https://github.com/GuntisTreulands/JigsawDemo/blob/master/JigsawExample/MainViewController.m thats the code I'm converting

Comment: That code is using some outdated practices. Now, Xcode automatically enables ARC to do all the memory management for you. All calls to `retain` or `release` are now obsolete.

Comment: hey if my ValueArray is ["1","2","3","4"] then it will get ValueArray[Counter-1] but it crashes when i do this ValueArray[Counter-1][2]

Comment: Because `["1","2","3","4"]` isn't a 2 dimensional array. It only contains one level of elements. A two dimensional array would be `[["1","2"],["3","4"]]`. Also, if your array contains strings, use `as NSString`. See the answer below or my edit.

Answer (score 0):

This does not always do the best job, but it can definitely help! It is a Objective-C to Swift converter.

Link https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/code